# getting blob Uri without connecting to Azure

Tags: azure

I've created a file system abstraction, where I store files with a relative path, e.g `/uploads/images/img1.jpg`.

These can then be saved both on local file system (relative to folder), or Azure.  Then, I can also ask a method to give me the url to access that relative path.

In Azure, currently this is being done similar to the below:

```
    public string GetWebPathForRelativePathOnUserContentStorage(string relativeFileFullPath)
    {

        var container = getCloudBlobContainer();
        CloudBlockBlob blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(relativeFileFullPath);

        return blob.Uri.ToString();
    }
```

On a normal website, there might be say 40 images in one page - So this get's called like 40 times.  Is this first of all **slow**?  I've noticed there is a particular pattern in the generated URL:

`https://[storageAccountName].blob.core.windows.net/[container_name]/[relative_path]`

Can I safely generate that URL without using the Azure storage API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> On a normal website, there might be say 40 images in one page - So
>   this get's called like 40 times. Is this first of all slow?

Not at all. The code you wrote above does not make any calls to storage. It just creates an instance of `CloudBlockBlob` object. If you were using `GetBlockBlobReferenceFromServer` method, then it would have been a different story because that method makes a call to storage.

> `I've noticed there is a particular pattern in the generated URL:
>
> _https://[storageAccountName].blob.core.windows.net/[container_name]/[relative_path]
>
> Can I safely generate that URL without using the Azure storage API?

Absolutely yes. Assuming you're using just standard stuff that would be perfectly fine. Non standard stuff would include things like using a custom domain for your blob storage or connecting to geo-secondary location of your storage account.

Comment: yes, but is one much faster than the other?  I would prefer to use the Azure API, but I was under the impression that would be slow.

Comment: I don't think you will be able to measure the time difference between the two. In one you're creating new objects (of type CloudBlockBlob) in a loop and in other you're just assigning some value to a string. So take your pick :). I would still go with the 1st approach because that kind of makes you fail safe in case down the road you try to create a blob url which does not use .blob.core.windows.net suffix.